# I do not understand where the "Error in which(z@data$cut) : argument to 'which' is not logical" is coming from when making 'mvmt' object from 'ltraj'

Tags: r

I am trying to make a `mvmt` object from the package `migrateR` in R.

I pass a `ltraj` from the package `adehabitatLT` to the `mvmtClass` command and get a `mvmt` object. The code works fine when doing this with a NSD (Net square displacement) model. However the package has an option to do this with elevation data, contained in the `ltraj` object as an `infoloc` as numeric values for elevation.

When I try the line:

```
dt.migrater.elev <- mvmtClass(dt.ltraj , fam = "elev")
```

I get the error:

```
Error in which(z@data$cut) : argument to 'which' is not logical
```

I do not understand where this error is coming from nor what the `which` command is supposed to do with the `cut` argument.

I can't see the `cut` argument in the `ltraj` object nor do I see the snippet `which(z@data$cut)` in the code for the [mvmtClass](https://github.com/dbspitz/migrateR/blob/master/migrateR/R/mvmtclass.r).

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what the exact issue is but I solved it by changing how I specify the `xy=` or the coordinates argument in the `as.ltraj` command when making the `ltraj` object. I did it before by specifying a `coordinates` attribute from `sp` package I made earlier, and now I just specify the columns in the dataframe that signify x and y.